# Providing self-signed SSL certs to Java HTTP Clients

Tags: java, ssl, ca, self-signed-certificate

By default, java does not connect to peers having self-signed certs that fail hostname/subject validation.

I have been told of one approach to this is to modify the cacerts that ship with the JVM, and another is to provide a trusted cert store to your app via

```
-Djavax.net.debug=SSL,trustmanager 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/trust.pkcs12 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=somePassword
```

But only one of these approaches is likely to be the best practice. Which is the best practice?

Comment: Best practice is to use a real certificate instead of a self-signed one. They're free from Let's Encrypt.

Comment: I wish I could. It's under consideration.